# Converting JS IDL to Python

Tags: python, idl, anchor-program-idl

does anyone have any example to convert IDL in Javascript to a useable one in Python?

I want to be able to decode data with the IDL in python

Answer (score 1):

IDL is just JSON data. You can simply use Python's `json` module to load it as a dictionary in your Python code.

For example:

```
import json

with open('idl.json') as f:
    data = json.loads(f)
    print(data)
```

If you're looking to use IDL to work with Solana Programs in Python, Then check out [Anchor.py](https://kevinheavey.github.io/anchorpy/)